# Problem with dagger injection in Fragment Test

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, junit4, androidx

Im basing my app development on [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) from android/architecture-components-samples including tests. I've already done my local unit tests but with the UI test I'm facing some trouble.

When I try to test any fragment I always get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized
```

This is my fragment test

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AccountListFragmentTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val executorRule = TaskExecutorWithIdlingResourceRule()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val countingAppExecutors = CountingAppExecutorsRule()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val dataBindingIdlingResourceRule = DataBindingIdlingResourceRule()

    private val navController = mock<NavController>()
    private val accountsLiveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<Accounts>>()
    private val triggerLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private lateinit var viewModel: AccountListViewModel

    @Before
    fun init() {
        viewModel = mock(AccountListViewModel::class.java)

        `when`(viewModel.trigger).thenReturn(triggerLiveData)
        `when`(viewModel.accounts).thenReturn(accountsLiveData)
        doNothing().`when`(viewModel).setTrigger(true)

        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer {
            AccountListFragment().apply {
                appExecutors = countingAppExecutors.appExecutors
                viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
            }
        }

        dataBindingIdlingResourceRule.monitorFragment(scenario)

        scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
            fragment.disableProgressBarAnimations()
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

And in my fragment I inject those dependendies like this

```
class AccountListFragment: Fragment(), Injectable {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    @Inject
    lateinit var appExecutors: AppExecutors

    ...
```

So I thought it would be something related to dependency injection.
In the GithubBrowserSample they mention that you need to create a TestApp and a CustomTestRunner to avoid Dagger Dependency Injection, I've already done that and added it to the build.gradle

```
class TestApp : Application()

class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, context: Context): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp::class.java.name, context)
    }
}

//build.gradle
defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.app.util.CustomTestRunner"
}
```

My viewModel already has the @OpenForTesting Annotation, I'm using a different viewModelFactory to provide my viewModels so I don't know what else I have to do to get it working.

I am running my tests with the Android Pixel 2 Api 29 emulator.

I appreciate all the help you can give me.